# MYSQL Date field showing random numbers, how to work out date?

Tags: mysql, database

I've exported a database (I need the data for a report) we have a 'start date' which is the start date of each project, but in MYSQL it isn't showing a date but instead a random number, it must say the date in some way because the tasks seem to go in order and the numbers change accordingly.

Can anybody tell me how to work out the date from the numbers, an example is below:

```
1337156712
```

and another:

```
1321443614
```

Any help will be great thanks!

OK I am using this PHP script to change the dates:

```
<?php

$TimeStamp = "1185422400"; 

$Time = date("m-d-Y", $TimeStamp);  

echo $Time;

?>
```

Can somebody help me turn it into an array so I can include around 500 dates and convert them all at once?

Thanks

Ricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your number is a Unix timestamp, [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) will give you a formatted date you can use with `DATETIME` fields:

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1321443614) AS time;
+---------------------+
| time                |
+---------------------+
| 2011-11-16 11:40:14 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are plenty of other time functions available, all of which are listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Great thanks, and how exactly can I convert these? Do I have to do it within MYSQL?

Comment: You can convert it to a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` formatted string using `FROM_UNIXTIME(column_name)`, and then use any other formatting functions you like.

Answer (score 2):

those are unix timestamps. They are the number of seconds past since Jan 1, 1970. There are a variety of function calls you can user to turn them into dates :)

I will be right back with a way to do it :)

`select from_unixtime(1321443614) as time`

arg! someone beat me to it!

Comment: I was just about to comment that it's `from_unixtime` not `from_unixtimestamp` before you edited - good catch.

Comment: lol :) well u r faster than me on the quickdraw, i had to look it up right quick and finger jammed it in (typed what i was thinkin not reading) :P